# Spring Security Login Issue on JBOSS EAP 7.1 and IE 11

Tags: spring-security

Below is the issue I am facing:

I have a web app using spring security for user authentication.

At first, it is using the **SessionFixationProtectionStrategy**, and it works fine with Tomcat 6, 7, 8, as well as WebLogic 12c.

However, issue occurs when I try to run my app on JBOSS EAP 7.1. In IE, it return this exception:

> ava.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000021: Session already invalidated
>       at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(InMemorySessionManager.java:543)
>       at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(InMemorySessionManager.java:529)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.applySessionFixation(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:58)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at sg.gov.ura.dax2.acegi.filter.RedirectURLFilter.doFilter(RedirectURLFilter.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:123)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Note that this issue only occur in IE 11. I tried with other browsers like Chrome and Edge, it just works fine.

I then try to replace this SessionFixationProtectionStrategy with **ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy** instead. This strategy also works fine with Chrome & Edge, but incurr another error occasionally in IE 11. From my log file, here is the error:

> 2019-01-07 10:48:50,660 DEBUG io.undertow.request.io -  -  - UT005013:
>   An IOException occurred -  java.io.IOException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) at
>   io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:242)
>   at
>   io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.flush(HttpResponseConduit.java:739)
>   at
>   io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.flush(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:229)

*Note that it is occasional, compare with the previous which is always error. Anyway, still it is error and not acceptable.*

Please advise what should I do to tackle the above mentioned.

I hereby attach the screenshot on the "network", of IE, Edge, and chrome

**IE11**
[image]

**Chrome**
[image]

**Edge**
[image]

Comment: To add in, I am using Spring Security 5.0

Comment: Hi dur, your are correct, in IE 11 it submit the j_spring_security_check twice; while in chrome it only submit once. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: OK. I managed to found the root cause, my login page some how trigger the Submit twice, when in IE 11. I will see how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` ditches the current session where the `UserPrincipal` is set after Spring Security authentication is made. Spring Security tries to copy as much data as it can from the old/current session to new session but it leaves out the `UserPrincipal` part which is user as a central part in JBoss EAP Security.

Because of this JBoss EAP now has no knowledge of the session.

Solution: Is to extend `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` and perform login using `HttpServletRequest.login(username, password)` which will re-establish the `UserPrincipal` need by JBoss EAP.